# Tkinter Grid Weirdness

Tags: python, tkinter

Made a simple grid-based Tkinter `Frame` subclass today.  It's master is a  `Tk()` object.

```
root = Tk()
root.title('Rep Logger UI')
root.geometry('500x500')

mother = rep_ui(master=root)
mother.mainloop()
```

All I wanted to do was **divide** the `rep_ui` window into two frames ( red, blue ) **of equal width**, and then put a few widgets in each.

But I'm not doing something right.  The red+blue frames don't completely fill the window.  Either they're not fully-filling the `rep_ui` class, or the `rep_ui` class isn't expanding properly inside its master (`root`) ?

Also, the blue and red frames are of different **`width`**, even though I column-configured them with the same **`weight`**-s.

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)

    """to make the rep_ui frame expand into the entire OS window."""

    self.master.rowconfigure(    0, weight = 1 )              # outer-bounds' row[0] weight set
    self.master.columnconfigure( 0, weight = 1 )              # outer-bounds' col[0] weight set

    self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)                                 # EWNS-sticky mode set

    self.columnconfigure(        0, weight = 1 )              # column[0] weight set
    self.columnconfigure(        1, weight = 1 )              # column[1] weight set

    self.rowconfigure(           0, weight = 1 )              #    row[0] weight set
    self.rowconfigure(           1, weight = 1 )              #    row[1] weight set


    """ left and right frames"""
    self.fl = Frame(self, bg="red")                           # RED  Frame ( left )
    self.fr = Frame(self, bg="blue")                          # BLUE Frame ( right )

    self.fl.grid( row=0, column=0,  sticky=N+S+W+E)           # .grid() RED  one
    self.fr.grid  row=0, column=1,  sticky=N+S+W+E)           # .grid() BLUE one
```

Here is a picture of the problem I'm describing:  [image: http://imgur.com/MkSE9yt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why are these windows different widths?**

The reason is pretty obvious: There's a text widget inside the red frame. The problem is that you added the `weight` parameter to both frames, but not to the widgets *inside*. For the text, you could use somethng like

```
self.fl.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.fl.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

**Why does this blank space exist?**

That's because you configured the row 1 here:

```
self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Though it's not used, it will appear. Remove or comment this line out to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The `weight` parameter only affects how *extra* space is distributed.  I.e. the grid manager first grids all the "grandchild" widgets, then if there is extra space, distributes it to the child widgets according to the supplied weights.  ([documented here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-config.html):  the weight parameter "gives the relative weight of this column or row when distributing the extra space")

A visual explanation:
[image: Diagram showing extra space distribution]

As for the blank space at the bottom, I think we need to see the rest of the code to figure that out.

Answer (score -2):

### You can try using the `place` geometry manager:

```
self.fl.place( relx = 0.0, rely = 0.0, relwidth = 0.5, relheight = 1.0 )
self.fr.place( relx = 0.5, rely = 0.0, relwidth = 0.5, relheight = 1.0 )
```

Using parent-widget relative scales is rather powerful, though still simple to code and validate and future-proof for re-scaling UI and does not suffer from other artifacts and unintended side-effects a complex UI-design may encounter during its life-cycle.

[image]

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
aLF  = Tkinter.Frame(  root, bg = "red" )
aRF  = Tkinter.Frame(  root, bg = "blue")
aLF.place(                   relx = 0.0,
                                 rely = 0.0, relwidth = 0.5, relheight = 1.0 )
aRF.place(                   relx = 0.5,
                                 rely = 0.0, relwidth = 0.5, relheight = 1.0 )
aTextR = Tkinter.Label( aRF, bg = "white", text = "aFR := frame right" )
aTextR.place(                relx = 0.0,
                                 rely = 0.0 )
aTextL = Tkinter.Label( aLF, bg = "white", text = "aFL := frame left" )
aTextL.place(                relx = 0.0,
                                 rely = 0.0 )
root.title( 'Rep Logger UI')
root.geometry( '500x500' )
root.lift()
```

and cross-validate

```
root.geometry( '500x500' )
root.geometry( '300x100' )
root.geometry( '400x300' )
root.geometry( '600x150' )
```